# How does the @Produces work in JavaEE context?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

From the CDI tutorial, i've discovered various examples and want to use them to inject some objects into an EJB (namely, I want to inject a [Neo4J connector](http://alexsmirnov.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/neo4j-java-ee-connector/) `GraphDatabaseService`). So, I have a target EJB :

```
@Stateless
public class Neo4JEJB implements Neo4JEJBInterface{

private @Inject @Named("the bidule") String bidule = "no bidule injected";
}
```

And a producer class containing a producer method

```
public class Producer {
public @Produces @Named("the bidule") String createBidulateur() {
    return "the bidule that should always work";
}
}
```

But, so far, i've been unable to see my `bidule` field having the correct value.

Is there something i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you are using `@Named` like the old Seam `@Name`. These two annotations have two different purposes. In CDI, `@Named` is only used to provide a name that can be used to reference the bean from within a facelet. On injection, a bean is identified by it's *type* and optionally using a qualifier. Since you are injecting a `String`, a qualifier is most likely necessary. You can create a qualifier annotation as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1217) and annotate your producer and injection point with it:

If you created the qualifier `@Bidule`

```
@Stateless
public class Neo4JEJB implements Neo4JEJBInterface{

    private @Inject @Bidule String bidule = "no bidule injected";
}

public class Producer {
    public @Produces @Bidule String createBidulateur() {
        return "the bidule that should always work";
    }
}
```

Also, I think (but am not sure) the bean that contains the producer method needs to be scoped ([see here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producermethods.html#d0e3365)).

Comment: From what I undestand of the `@Named` annotation, it's here to disambiguate when more than one injectable objects can be found (and by the way to avoid annotation explosion). Isn't it the case ?

Comment: Nope, it's for use in EL expressions as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e664), qualifier annotations are for disambiguation.

Comment: Seems like this time I won't escape the Seam documentation full reading.

Comment: I would highly recommend the Seam Weld documentation over the Java EE 6 Tutorial. The Seam team do a much better job of explaining it in a user friendly way.